# Mysql - Ignore warning when inserting new row if the entire same one has existed

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my first question in stackoverflow and I am not native English speaker. If I does not ask well, bear with me please.

Suppose I have a table, which `_id` is a primary key.

```
| _id | value1 | value2 |
|-----|--------|--------|
|   1 |  apple | banana |
|   2 | orange |  melon |
```

I wish that:

- If I try querying `INSERT INTO table_name (_id, value1, value2) VALUES (1, 'apple', 'banana')` then nothing happens because the entire row is same.
- If I try querying `INSERT INTO table_name (_id, value1, value2) VALUES (2, 'apple', 'tomato')` then I get warning, since there exists at least one column not equaled.

Is there any concise statement in mysql so that I can do suck work?

Comment: I had an answer for your other question just as before deleted ..:), you may try undeleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a unique index on `_id`:

```
create unique index unq_table_id on table(_id);
```

Then, you will not be able to insert another row with the same `_id`.  You can create unique indexes for `value1` and `value2` if you also want these to be unique.

The behavior is not exactly what you specify.  If you attempt to insert *any* row with an existing `_id` -- regardless of the values in the other columns -- then an error will occur.  You can bypass the error using `insert ignore` or `on duplicate key update`, if you like.